# Improper integral definition explanation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definition, improper-integrals

[image]

This is the definition from my book and I don't quite understand what does ' all closed intervals $[c,d]$ ' mean. Does that mean there can be an arbitrary number of such intervals, all which do not overlap each other, and for which there is an assigned regulated function to all of these intervals? I think I'm confused because later in the definition it writes that $c$ and $d$ tend to the right limit of $a$ and left limit of $b$.(Hence there can only be one interval $[c,d]$ ?)

Also, what would happen if we did not take c to the right limit of a and d to the left limit of b. As in, why are we taking the limits of these intervals to be $a+$ and $b-$ ? Can't we just integrate it from a to b?

Comment: What does "regulated" mean in your book?

Comment: f is regulated means that there is a step function sequence which is convergent to f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot simply integrate from $a$ to $b$ since $\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx$ is undefined (unless $[a,b]$ is a subset of the domain $D_f$ of $f$). On the other hand, if $[c,d]\subset D_f$, then $\int_c^df(x)\,\mathrm dx$ *is* defined. And so basically we defined $\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx$ as the limit of these integrals (when $c$ goes to $a$ and $d$ goes to $b$).

Comment: Why would it not be definded? Could you maybe give me an example?

Comment: The Riemann integral is defined only for bounded function from an interval $[a,b]$ into $\mathbb R$. So, take, say $f\colon(0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac1x}$. It is unbounded and therefore, it makes no sense to talk about the Riemann integral $\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: Okay, I understand now, thanks. But what about the intervals [c,d]?

Comment: Those are subsets of $D_f$. For each of them, the integral $\int_c^df(x)\,\mathrm dx$ is defined. And the integral of $f$ is the limit of these integrals. So, taking the example from my previous example:\begin{align}\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx&=\lim_{c\to0}\int_c^1\sqrt{\frac1x}\,\mathrm dx\\&=\lim_{c\to0}2-2\sqrt c\\&=2.\end{align}

Comment: Just to clarify, there is one interval [c,d] for which it is defined on the domain of f? Or there can be any number of such intervals(for example [c,d] , [c',d'] , [c'',d''] , ...  this is when the function is not defined on some intervals) which are defined on the domain of f?

Comment: There are infinitely many intervals $[c,d]$ which are subsets of $D_f$.

Comment: ok ok thank you!